# Is there a php equivalent to mySQL's IN?

Tags: php, if-statement

In writing select statements in mySQL, if I want to pull records where a column value equals one of a number of values, I can say something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myColumn IN(1,5,7)
```

Is the only way to accomplish something similar in PHP with OR?

```
if($category == 1 || $category == 5 || $category == 7) {
   // do something
}
```

Comment: You can use a switch if you dislike the if statement style. Possibly off-topic.

Comment: I know about switch, but since I need to do the same thing for all the values, it seems kind of silly to split them out that way.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See the [`in_array()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) function.

E.g.:

```
$list = array(1, 5, 7);
if (in_array($category, $list)) {
  // do something
}
```

Or, more compactly:

```
if (in_array($category, array(1, 5, 7))) {
  // do something
}
```

Comment: Thank you! How did I not know about this before?!

Answer (score 3):

Sure [in_array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php), i.e.

```
if( in_array( $category, array( 1, 5, 7 ) ) ) {
```

Answer (score 2):

yes, It is [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

You can check the value if it is in array.

```
$categories =array(1,5,7);
if (in_array($category, $categories))
{
  //do stuff
}
```